# Sending email with hotmail in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

I am trying to figure out how to send emails using codeigniter, and I succesfully did so using my gmail account.

But the problem is that I do not known how to do it with my hotmail account...

Heres the code which uses gmail:

```
<?php

class Email extends CI_Controller
{
function index() 
{   
        $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp', 
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'someEmail@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'Password'

    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('someEmail@gmail.com', 'Me');
    $this->email->to('AnotherGuy');     
    $this->email->subject('This is an email test');     
    $this->email->message('It is working. Great!');


    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo 'Your email was sent.';
    }

    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use a similar code, but as was mentioned, you need to change the smtp variables. 
Hotmail: 
server:smtp.live.com
port:587

Try:

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp', 
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.live.com',
    'smtp_port' => 587,
    'smtp_user' => 'someEmail@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'Password'

);
```

[Source](http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/mail-settings.html)